# Unmanaged byte array to managed structure

Tags: c#, memory-management, serialization

I have a need to turn byte arrays into various structures.

First version:

```
public static object ConvertBytesToStructure(object target, byte[] source, Int32 targetSize, int startIndex, int length)
    {
        if (target == null)
            return null;

        IntPtr p_objTarget = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(targetSize);
        try
        {
            Marshal.Copy(source, startIndex, p_objTarget, length);
            Marshal.PtrToStructure(p_objTarget, target);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(p_objTarget);
        }

        return target;
    }
```

I have found that when i calling to the first version a lot of times in a second - i getting poor performance.

So i trying to improve that to the version 2:

```
  private static T ReadUsingMarshalUnsafe<T>(byte[] data, int startIndex, int length)
        {
            byte[] fixedData = new byte[length];
            unsafe
            {
                fixed (byte* pSource = data, pTarget = fixedData)
                {
                    int index = 0;
                    for (int i = startIndex; i < data.Length; i++)
                    {
                        pTarget[index] = pSource[i];
                        index++;
                    }
                }

                fixed (byte* p = &fixedData[0])
                {
                    return (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(new IntPtr(p), typeof(T));
                }
            }
        }
```

I have found that this version getting very good performance..

But i want to getting your code review - maybe i'll have any memory leak? maybe i can to do this with efficent another way?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? If on .NET Core 2.1 or above then one can rely on the native `MemoryMarshal` class which has a method `Read<T>` that I believe matches your needs. Alternatively, one can import the *System.Memory* NuGet package if using .NET Framework 4.5 or above; it is not as optimized but should work well.

Comment: Could also show the `struct`s you are using?

Comment: @Kittoes0124, .NETFramework 4.0 client

Comment: @t3chb0t i'll attach an example

Answer (score 6):

Expanding on my comment; below you'll find a very simple program that compares the method I suggested with your original example. The results on my machine show that the `MemoryMarshal` class is about 85x faster. You might want to experiment a bit and try running a similar test with a larger struct; maybe your method is faster for the specific problem that you're trying to solve.

**Comparison Code:**

```
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public readonly struct SomeStruct
{
    private readonly ulong m_x;
    private readonly ulong m_y;
    private readonly ulong m_z;

    public ulong X => m_x;
    public ulong Y => m_y;
    public ulong Z => m_z;

    public SomeStruct(ulong x, ulong y, ulong z) {
        m_x = x;
        m_y = y;
        m_z = z;
    }
}

public class Race
{
    private readonly byte[] m_data = new byte[] {
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        1, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    };

    [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
    public SomeStruct A() => MemoryMarshal.Read<SomeStruct>(m_data);
    [Benchmark]
    public SomeStruct B() => Program.ReadUsingMarshalUnsafe<SomeStruct>(m_data, 0, m_data.Length);
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<Race>();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static T ReadUsingMarshalUnsafe<T>(byte[] data, int startIndex, int length) {
        byte[] fixedData = new byte[length];
        unsafe {
            fixed (byte* pSource = data, pTarget = fixedData) {
                int index = 0;
                for (int i = startIndex; i < data.Length; i++) {
                    pTarget[index] = pSource[i];
                    index++;
                }
            }

            fixed (byte* p = &fixedData[0]) {
                return (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(new IntPtr(p), typeof(T));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**BenchmarkDotNet Results:**

[image: Benchmark results.]

Comment: MemoryMarshal  is not exists in old framework:\

Answer (score 0):

first of all, thanks for your great example.

I update my little program based of your answer to benchmark it.

The project should be  .NETFramework 4.0 client, but for the benchmark i change it to be  .NETFramework 4.0.

```
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
public class SomeStructure
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
    public char[] szF1;
    public char cF2;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
    public char[] szF3;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 7)]
    public char[] szF4;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 7)]
    public char[] szF5;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 7)]
    public char[] szF6;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 9)]
    public char[] szF7;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 9)]
    public char[] szF8;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 9)]
    public char[] szF9;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 9)]
    public char[] szF10;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1)]
    public char[] cF11;
    public char cF12;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
    public char[] cF13;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 7)]
    public char[] szF14;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 9)]
    public char[] szF15;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 7)]
    public char[] szF16;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 9)]
    public char[] szF17;
}

public class Race
{
    //[Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
    //public SomeStruct A() => MemoryMarshal.Read<SomeStruct>(_data);
    [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
    public object A() => Program.ConvertBytesToStructure(new SomeStructure(), _data, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SomeStructure)), 0, _data.Length);

    [Benchmark]
    public SomeStructure B() => Program.ConvertBytesToStructureV2<SomeStructure>(_data, 0, _data.Length);

    private readonly byte[] _data = new byte[] {
        49, 50, 49, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56,
        49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 49, 50, 51, 52,
        53, 54, 55, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 49,
        50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 49, 50, 51,
        52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53,
        54, 55, 56, 57, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55,
        56, 57, 49, 97, 49, 50, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53,
        54, 55, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57,
        49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 49, 50, 51, 52,
        53, 54, 55, 56, 57
};

}

 public class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<Race>();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    public static object ConvertBytesToStructure(object target, byte[] source, Int32 targetSize, int startIndex, int length)
    {
        if (target == null)
            return null;

        IntPtr p_objTarget = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(targetSize);
        try
        {
            Marshal.Copy(source, startIndex, p_objTarget, length);
            Marshal.PtrToStructure(p_objTarget, target);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(p_objTarget);
        }

        return target;
    }

    public static T ConvertBytesToStructureV2<T>(byte[] data, int startIndex, int length)
    {
        byte[] fixedData = new byte[length];
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (byte* pSource = data, pTarget = fixedData)
            {
                int index = 0;
                for (int i = startIndex; i < data.Length; i++)
                {
                    pTarget[index] = pSource[i];
                    index++;
                }
            }

            fixed (byte* p = &fixedData[0])
            {
                return (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(new IntPtr(p), typeof(T));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The results:

[image]

If i understand good - it seems that according to the Benchmark results,the first method is faster than the second method.

But these are not the results I see in my system.

More details:
It's multi-threading system, i've a service that listen to another service and register to his event, when the event is raised with unmanaged data (byte[]) i convert that to the my cutom managed object.

So far so good, but when i stress the system by sending thousands of events (~20000) per second, The original method (ConvertBytesToStructure) getting poor performance, and the new method getting excellent performance..